# Android: GridView resetting position in getView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm populating a GridView with a list of stages, currently 4. When calling `getView(...)` 0, 1 and 2 load fine, showing the correct position number.

However, on position *3* the number is reset to 0, giving me the list: `0, 1, 2, 0`.

```
public class ExampleGrid extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;

    public ExampleGrid(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Button levelButton;    
        if (convertView == null) {
            String positionText = position + "";
            levelButton = new Button(mContext);
            levelButton.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.mm_stage) + positionText);
            levelButton.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        } else {
            levelButton = (Button) convertView;
        }

        return levelButton;
    }
}
```

This prints `0, 1, 2, 0`. If I set the `getCount()` method to return a larger value, the pattern is repeated. e.g.: `0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, ...`

**Update**: changed code to a more generic example. Now the numbers get loaded fine at first but as soon as I scroll down the list, they lose any order.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by keeping a reference to the buttons in the `BaseAdapter` and using this reference instead of checking `convertView` from the `getView(...)` method.
**Note** `mButtons`:

```
public class ExampleGrid extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;

    private Button[] mButtons;

    public ExampleGrid(Context c){
        mContext = c;
        mButtons = new Button[getCount()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return mButtons[pos];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Button levelButton;    
        if (mButtons[position] == null){ 
            String positionText = position + "";
            levelButton = new Button(mContext);
            levelButton.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.mm_stage) + positionText);
            levelButton.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            mButtons[position] = levelButton;
        } else {
            levelButton = mButtons[position];
        }

        return levelButton;
    }
}
```